# Java Hmac Hash to C#

Tags: c#, java

I have a need to create a HMACSHA1 in C# to work with a Java web service.  I believe that the Java implementation may be flawed because I've tested my result extensively using some online services.  I don't know Java very well and I need to make my C# code produce the same has as the Java code, even if it is not technically correct.

Java Version:

```
public static byte[] computeSignature(String algorithm, byte[] data, byte[] sharedSecret) {
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(sharedSecret), algorithm);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(secretKey);
        mac.update(data);
        return Base64.encode(mac.doFinal());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

C# Version:

```
private string GetHash(string message, string key)
{
    message = message.Replace("\r", "");

    Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
    var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte);
    hmacsha1.Initialize();

    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    var hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    var sigB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
    return sigB64;
}
```

Using the following message and secret key:

Message: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Secret: `key`

I get the following results:

C#: `3nybhbi3iqa8ino29wqQcBydtNk=`

Java: `K6f3B61fGHxBLeMQZYPDER1mjeg=`

I'm fairly certain the Base64 encoding is where the difference is happening, but I'm not sure.

So, my question is -- How can I make my C# code produce the same output as the Java example?

P.S.  The java code has the following import:

```
com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;
```

**Edit:**
Here is how the java function gets called:

```
    String signature = new String(HmacUtils.computeSignature("HmacSHA1", canonicalRepresentation.getBytes(), sharedSecret.getBytes()));
    String authorization = "HMAC " + publicKey + " " + signature;
    clientRequest.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, Lists.<Object>newArrayList(authorization));
```

Comment: Your Java isn't using UTF8.

Comment: How are you calling `computeSignature`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch -- I added the calling code.

Comment: @SLaks -- that may be, but the question is how to make the C# version produce the same hash.

Comment: Your Base64 encode should return a String, shouldn't it?

Comment: That one returns a byte[], but the caller wraps it in a new String ctor.

Comment: @MichaelSanford Try an `ASCIIEncoding` in the C# version.